# Finding corresponding encrypted file on encfs

Tags: encryption, fuse

Hopefully a very simple question.

I have a read-only mount, and a encfs FUSE mount reads over that to decrypt the files. How do I know which encrypted file each decrypted file relates to?

For example: I want to delete a file, however won't be able to do that via the read-only filesystem. How do I know the true filename?

I am possibly looking for a more programmatic way of doing this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found this is possible `encfsctl`. You can use `encode` function to turn the human readable name into the real path on the filesystem.

```
$ ENCFS6_CONFIG='encfs6.xml' encfsctl encode /encfs/mountpoint readable/name/in/mountpoint
EncFS Password: 
decryptedname
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/encfsctl.1.html

Comment: Note: This also works in the other direction with decode.  The ENCFS6_CONFIG=... part is optional.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution I am not amazingly happy with. I can make up two directories `encrypted` and `decrypted` and use the same `.encfs6.xml` file to mount the `decrypted/` directory as the encfs mountpoint.

I can then `mkdir -p decrypted/parent/of/file` and `touch` the filename. Then if I check in `decrypted` I will have the full path of the encrypted file I want.

It's not elegant but it's a solution. Does anyone have any better ideas?